# How to recover from deleting Xcode CoreSimulator devices from disk?

Tags: xcode, xcode-simulator

By mistake I deleted `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices` from my Mac so all my Xcode simulators were deleted.

Now none of my Xcode projects run. When I try to, an alert shows that no simulator is selected in select device.

Comment: As I am not a developer I am guessing on this, but did you try re-installing X-Code?

Answer (score 26):

To get back to a vanilla state, quit Xcode, Simulator, Instruments, and any other CoreSimulator clients that you have and run:

```
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService 2> /dev/null
rm -rf ~/Library/*/CoreSimulator
```

Comment: This is the answer. did the trick after the Xcode 11 update.

Comment: This answer still works as of Xcode 12.4. Thanks!

Comment: Amazing! I deleted all simulators by mistake. Now they are all back. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can add new simulators inside the Xcode. Simply press <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to open **Devices** window. There on the lower left side you have small "`+`".

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can download simulator from internet and add it in you Xcode package content or directly select option "DOWNLOAD SIMULATOR" from Xcode.

Answer (score -2):

Finally, I solve my problem by updating Xcode you can solve this problem..